# Como verificar se houve mudanças em um ClientDataSet

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

Uso **Delphi XE7**, preciso verificar se teve inserção/edição no `ClientDataSet` antes de fechar uma determinada tela, mas pode acontecer de eu fechar a tela e ele não está mais em estado de inserção/edição e mesmo assim teve alguma mudança no DataSet, por isso preciso de algo que indique que teve essas alterações, se existir alguma inserção/edição mostrar uma mensagem.

Sei que tem a função:

```
if MyClientDataSet.Modified then
 mensagem
```

mas não funciona, posso controlar cada vez que ele da um Append/Edit em uma variável, mas queria saber se o próprio componente já tem uma função que verifique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achei o que estava procurando, após algumas pesquisas, vou explicar como usar.

Existe uma variável do próprio componente `TClientDataSet` chamada **LogChanges** uma varíavel Boleana que vem como True por default. Com isso o `TClientDataSet` começa a alimentar a varíavel inteira **ChangeCount**, mostrando quantos registros sofreram mudanças.

Assim consigo resolver minha dúvida.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode testar o `state`:

```
if cds.state id dsEditModes then ...
```

ou, ainda, se alterações pendentes (sem `applyupdate`):

```
if cds.ChangeCount > 0 then ...
```

Para testar no fechamento do form, o ideal é utiliza o evento `OnCloseQuery` que tem um parâmetro onde se pode impedir o fechamento.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar algo assim:

```
if (meucds.state in [dsEdit, dsInsert]) then
begin
   // seu código aqui...
end;
```

Neste exemplo ele também considera se está em estado de inserção, se desejar apenas verificar se está em estado de edição, basta remover o dsInsert.

Comment: Mas quando eu fechar a tela e não tiver em estado de Inserção/edição e mesmo assim teve alteração,  ele vai deixar passar.

Comment: Não, pois ele entra em estado edição automaticamente após algum dado ter sido alterado.

Comment: Consegui resolver Fabio, o que eu precisava é saber se o TClientDataSet sofreu mudanças, não queria saber em que estado ele estava.

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução mais completa seria utilizar o `ClientDataSet.UpdateStatus`. Para cada registro, ele informa se o mesmo foi inserido (`usInserted`), editado (`usModified`) ou deletado (`usDeleted`, mas para vê-lo, você precisa mudar o `StatusFilter` do `ClientDataSet`).

Essas informações estão disponíveis para quando o `ClientDataSet` está cacheando os dados (`LogChanges`) e especialmente a `usModified` só está corretamente setada quando o `DataSet` está em modo `dsBrowse` (pq não há como saber se o registro foi editado até que seja dado um post).